# for loop in python for log-scale increments

Tags: python

I want to know if it is possible to loop over a variable with log-scale increments. More specifically I want to generate values for q from 1E-10 to 1E-2 in log-scale increments as 1E-10, 1E-9, 1E-8, 1E-7,1E-6,1E-5,1E-4,1E-3,1E-2. Can you suggest how I can write a for loop for this?

Comment: `[10**i for i in range(-10,-1)]` should do

Comment: If you .have NumPy available, you could simply use `for q in numpy.logspace(-10, -2, 9): ...`

Answer (score 4):

simple list comprehension and `range` (`-1` is the upper bound and is not reached):

```
>>> [10**i for i in range(-10,-1)]
[1e-10, 1e-09, 1e-08, 1e-07, 1e-06, 1e-05, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01]
```

for lazy-evaluation, just replace `[]` by `()` to create a generator comprehension instead:

```
(10**i for i in range(-10,-1))
```

Comment: Probably should mention that for future looping purposes OP may want a generator rather than a list.

Comment: One might want to add that for the lazy evaluation you can then do this:for x in (10**i for i in range(-10,-1)): print (x)

Answer (score 0):

try [np.geomspace()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html)

```
>>> list(np.geomspace(1e-10, 1e-2, 9))
[1e-10, 1e-9, 1e-8, 1e-7, 1e-6, 1e-5, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01]
```